# ajax method is executed after binding the href to the linkbutton..which should execute before

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an issue related to jquery when using colorbox plugins

```
$("[id$=LinkButton1]").click(function() {
 
        var filename=$(this).text();
      
     
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
         url: "WebService.asmx/lnkbtn1",
         data: '{filename: \'' + filename + '\'}',
          
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {
        
         filename=msg.d;
             alert("filename1="+msg.d); ----------1.
            
          
          }
         
        });
         alert('Outside ');------2
       //  $(".iframe").attr('href',filename);---------3
         $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"50%", height:"100%"});
   
     });
     

        });
```

Here When i click on linkbutton with a filename in a gridview

```
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'
                        Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>' CommandName="ViewImages" CssClass="iframe"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am using colorbox jquery plugin... here what happen is i get the filename... then that file name i pass to the webservice method(lnkbtn1), process the file name then I will get a filename from that i have to display it in popup colorbox...

But there is one issue here 2. is executed first and then 1. is executed so i am not able to bind file name to the 'href'

**EDIT**
when the filename is passed to the webmethod it is first converted into html.. Suppose if the filetype is word document or excedlfile then its first convert to html. Suppose the file name is notes.doc.. then

1. filename(notes.doc) is passed to the webmethod
2. convert notes.doc to notes.html
3. webmethod returns notes.html

   Reason for converting to html because the .doc file content will not display in iframe

Please help...

Comment: pls any one have any idea....

Comment: I think no one able to solve this issue....

Answer (score 0):

$ajax is asynchronous. The code that needs results from $ajax must be in a success handler.
Your code should at least be something like (changed as few things as I could, as I don't know the purpose of `return true;` or the exact purpose of the `filename` variable)

```
$("[id$=LinkButton1]").click(function() {    
        var filename=$(this).text();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
         url: "WebService.asmx/lnkbtn1",
         data: '{filename: \'' + filename + '\'}',

          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {
                filename=msg.d;
                alert("filename1="+msg.d); //----------1.
                alert('Outside ');//------2
                $(".iframe").attr('href',filename);//---------3
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"50%", height:"100%"});
               }
        });
      return true;
     });    
 });
```

Comment: @Babu this did not solve your event ordering issue ? (updated the code to have syntactically correct comments)